# How do you use Wordpress Ajax calls for authenticated users without cookies?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, cordova

I have Wordpress setup as a "mothership site".  My users are registered there and so forth.  From one of my client sites, I would like to make ajax api calls to the Wordpress site and get results back based on the users login information.

So if Wordpress user "Bob" has a custom field "color" that is green, I would love to be able to look this up via an AJAX call.

But because my app can't use cookies (Phonegap),how do I tell Wordpress this request really IS coming from Bob?

I can store variables locally using window.localStorage.

So in an ideal world, I would attempt an login via ajax to wordpress (easy), and if successful, create a api token.  This is passed back to the client which stores in in say window.localStorage.api_token.  All subsequent ajax calls pass this api_token which I could use to get information about the sender.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the WP REST API and OAuth authentication: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Plugin that enables you that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/

More on the complete REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involved OAuth.